# Custom Shortcuts to Adjust Sound Volume Not Working

Tags: sound, keyboard, shortcut-keys, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a desktop which runs Ubuntu 16.04 on which I've set up custom shortcuts to adjust the volume:

Volume up: `amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%+ unmute`

Volume down: `amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%- unmute`

I recently got a new desktop computer with Ubuntu 18.04, and when I try to set the same volume shortcuts this does not work. Instead, it just mutes everything. However, when I run these commands in the terminal they work properly and adjust the sound volume as expected, so I can't figure out why they don't work as shortcut commands.

For the record, I'm using the built-in keyboard settings program to set the custom shortcuts, and I'm setting the shortcuts as `Ctrl+1` for volume down, `Ctrl+2` for volume up.

UPDATE: Based on PRATAP's feedback, I can get this working by placing the `amixer` calls in a pair of scripts in my `~/bin` folder and then making the shortcut keys point to these scripts. Note for anyone doing this, you must include `#!/bin/bash` at the top of each script, use `chmod` to set it to executable, plus use the full path to the script in your shortcut (`~` doesn't necessarily get expanded by your shortcut).

So now my question is this: why does it work to make the shortcut point to a script, but not when the shortcut executes the code directly? Why is this behaviour different in Ubuntu 18.04 vs. 16.04?

Comment: i tried it with two scripts and made those scripts as ctrl+1 and 2 as shortcuts.. it worked as expected.